# Authentication Flow in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm having issue creating the authentication flow of my app. What I actually want is to navigate user conditionally based on their role.

By default, I have created an AuthStack which is basically a stackNavigator and it has a login page. Once user logs in, we receive user's role through a network request. Next I navigate him to a simple home page that returns nothing but switchNavigator based on his role. Here's the code for better clarity.

```
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({
    Login: {
        screen: Login
    },
    SignUp: {
        screen: SignUp
    },
    Home: {
        screen: Home
    }
},
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Login',
        headerMode: 'none'
    });
```

```
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AuthStack);
const Navigation = () => {
    return <AppContainer />
}
```

When user logs in, I redirect him to Home screen shown in above mentioned stack. Here's the code in Home screen:

```
const Home = (props) => {
    const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootNavigator(props.user.role))
    return <AppContainer />
}
```

Here I create a new app container (which might be the bad practice, advice please). And RootNavigator is a helper function which returns a switchNavigator:

```
export const RootNavigator = (user) => {
return createSwitchNavigator({
    Admin: {
        screen: AdminDrawerNavigator
    },
    Reporter: {
        screen: ReporterDrawerNavigator
    }
}, 
{
    initialRouteName: user === 'admin'? 'Admin': 'Reporter'
})
}
```

This all works fine but it seems switchNavigator doesn't seem to work correctly. If I press back button of hardware, it goes back to login page. Thank you for your time. Please suggest the possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset you history navigation :

```
NavigationActions.reset({
   index: 1,
   actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ 
                  routeName: 'Admin' 
                }),
            ]
});
```

Comment: Where do I add this NavigationActions?